# Question on finite dimensional distribution of Markov Chain

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $\{ X_{n} \}$ is a Markov Chain and $X_{o} \sim \pi$ (where $\pi$ is the stationary measure), it follows that the MC is identically distributed.

I have a question about the finite dimensional distributions.  Specifically, I would like to know if the following equality is true:

$P( \omega :(X_{0}, X_{1}, \dots, X_{n}) \in A) =  P( \omega :(X_{0}, X_{0}, \dots, X_{0}) \in A)$

If so, how can we justify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim isn't true. While starting a MC in its stationary measure implies that every $X_n$ has the same distribution as $X_0$, it doesn't follow that the sequence $(X_0,\ldots,X_n)$ has the same distribution as $(X_0,\ldots,X_0)$.

For a counterexample, take a simple MC that bounces deterministically between two states, $A$ and $B$. The stationary distribution puts equal mass on the two states. Starting in this stationary distribution, the vector $(X_0,X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ has equal mass on $(A,B,A,B,\ldots)$ and $(B,A,B,A,\ldots)$ while $(X_0,X_0,\ldots,X_0)$ puts equal mass on $(A,A,\ldots,A)$ and $(B,B,\ldots,B)$.

Comment: Can I at least say this is true of the vectors $(X_{0},\dots,X_{n})$ and $(X_{k},\dots,X_{k+n})$ for some $k \in \Bbb N$?  That's what I'm really trying to show.

Comment: Yep, that's true for every $k$,

Comment: I figured, but how can I see it?  I don't know how to justify it.

Comment: If you remember, you answered the finite dimensional distribution question yesterday, which was very helpful.

Comment: I remember :) If the state space is countable, you can argue by proving it on sets $A$ of the form $(s_0,s_1,\ldots,s_n)$ where the $s$'s are individual states (since every set $A$ is the union of such singleton sets): Use conditioning and the Markov property to write a product: $P(X_0=s_0, X_1=s_1, \ldots, X_n=s_n)=P(X_0=s_0)P(X_1=s_1|X_0=s_0)P(X_2=s_2|X_1=s_1) \times \cdots \times P(X_n=s_n|X_{n-1}=s_{n-1})$

Comment: ...  and similarly for the other probability. Then note that all the corresponding factors in the two products are equal.